# Is there a string method that returns True if the string value consists of character & numbers?

Tags: python

What is the string method returns True if the string value is Consists of characters & numbers in python-programming-language?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Open Letter to Students with Homework Problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). You can't just dump your problem statement here and expect us to do it for you. It's also a good idea to take the [tour], read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic], and [ask].

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
a = "test123"
containsAlpahNumeric = a.isalnum()
print(containsAlphaNumeric)
```

Will return `true`. `isalnum()` (as the name suggests) checks for alphanumeric characters.

**Edit**

Given the comments of OP, they were looking for something to find if the string contained alpha **and** numeric characters (not one or the other). I propose the following code for that:

```py
a = "test123"
containsAlpahNumeric = a.isalnum() and not a.isalpha() and not a.isdigit()
```

Comment: Dear alexpiers thanks for your subscribe above, I have tried the .isalnum() method but it did not give what I want it will still returns True if the inputed value is consist of characters only in mean while what I am looking for is to returns True only if the inputed value is consisted of characters & numbers, Thanks again.

Comment: @Drake_sb, based on this comment your question is very unclear. Again, I ask you to please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Some examples might help. But a string consisting of letters only _does_ consist of only numbers and letters. If you want at least one of each you need to say so.

Comment: You can use a combination of `isalnum()`, `isalpha()` and `isdigit()`. So something like `a.isalnum() and not a.isalpha() and not a.isdigit()` should do what you are looking for, if I understand you question.

Comment: Please accept the answer as correct if it is what you were looking for :)

Comment: @alexpiers I am new here, could you please tell me how can I serve your request.

Comment: There should be check marks next to answers; if you click the check, you accept the answer.